# how to use odata query for $filter in GUID

Tags: c#, odata, guid

when trying to use the $filter in odata query, the startswith and endswith operator throwing exception "no function arguments match". But the eq operator only working without any problem. what are the operators support GUID in odata $filter and how to use the startswith, endswith in GUID.

Comment: You cannot use the `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` because the GUID class does not contain those methods. But more to the point. That is completely against the point of a GUID, as a correctly generated GUID should be random. Exposing such a method in OData would constitute a security hole.

Comment: then can we use 'eq' operator only to the $filter? or any other operators is possible. please share us any msdn link regarding supported operator parmeter for GUID.

Comment: thanks,is able to use GUID into string

Comment: in OData, you can first 'Cast' guid to string, then use the string operation. For cast, you can refer the E2E test cases in https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/Cast/CastTest.cs

Comment: @SamXu I'm getting this exception when casting to string "The child type 'Edm.String' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types"

Comment: @SamXu and also i'm using like this, `"endswith(cast(Id, 'Edm.String'),'e')" `i'm getting unknown function cast exception.

Comment: @MarvinSmit, can't understand

Comment: CAST supports in Web API OData V4.  What version are you using?